# Application window to be activated every 3 minutes

Tags: vbscript

I have multiple windows on the screen and I want one of these windows to be activated every 3 minutes with a VBScript.

Here's what I've tried:

```
objShell.AppActivate "Program Name"
```

but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: In an application, the application that I watched while working is not active. I need to activate this application every 3 minutes.

Comment: Does the window you want to activate have the title you specified? Did you try with the PID instead of the window title?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this. Only a newly started script can change the foreground window (within two seconds) or the script is the foreground window (ie it has a UI).

Programs cannot mess with users' windows unless the user is working in that program.